# How to disable the printing tomcat error?

Tags: spring

[image]

If the exception occur in the Filters. there is error messes. not log!.

I really want to disable printing the error.

My application works on springboot

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
```

Comment: Fix the thing that leads to the error. The servlet throws an exception upon execution. Get the stacktrace that lead to this.

Comment: @M.Deinum There is my custom Handler Interceptor. and I have to check some condition and throw exception. there is no choice. `rg.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] ` ...

Comment: Well if you are throwing an exception what would you expect tomcat to do?

Comment: Tomcat is bubbling the exception to be handled by Spring error handling, so it's not unreasonable to ask it to not log.